# Orchard CMS with current site as subsite

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, orchardcms

it is my understanding that Orchard can be extended, but cannot be integrated into existing sites. I need a CMS module but refactoring of current site into Orchard Module is not an option. Would it be a viable alternative to have Orchard as the main site and the current site as a subsite of Orchard? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Ariel

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "subsite"?

Comment: What I mean is to have the Orchard site as the root site in IIS (say www.site.com) and the current MVC/WebAPI/Angular site as a subsite in IIS ([www.site.com/app).

Comment: Yes, that is doable, but you'll have to tweak the web.config in that directory to prevent it from inheriting settings from Orchard.

Comment: Excelent, excelent point. Thanks for pointing that out. If you add it as an aswer, I'll accept it. Best regards!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is doable, but you'll have to tweak the web.config in that directory to prevent it from inheriting settings from Orchard.